# Hive comparison with aggregate result from subquery

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, delta

I have a table (e.g. called **Source**) like this:

```
-------------
|Name|ID|...|
-------------
|A   |1 |...|
|A   |2 |...|
|A   |3 |...|
|B   |1 |...|
|B   |2 |...|
|C   |1 |...|
-------------
```

so each **Name** may have multiple entries, each with an incrementing **ID** (which is in turn partitioned by **Name** as you probably got it by now).

Now, I have another table (called **Dest**) where I load from the **Source** table in e.g. daily batches. However, I only want to load the delta from **Source**, so if my **Dest** table is like this:

```
-------------
|Name|ID|...|
-------------
|A   |1 |...|
|A   |2 |...|
|B   |1 |...|
-------------
```

I only want to copy the difference from **Source** to **Dest** , which would be:

```
-------------
|Name|ID|...|
-------------
|A   |3 |...|
|B   |2 |...|
|C   |1 |...|
-------------
```

For other reasons I cannot use a timestamp or a minus for this, so the only way to find the difference would be by getting the **MAX(ID)** for each **Name** and retrieving only the entries **> MAX(ID)** for each **Name**.

The quickest implementation would be through a subquery which prepares all the **MAX(ID)** for each **Name**, and use that to eliminate the smaller **ID**s:

```
SELECT s.* FROM Source s 
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT d.NAME, MAX(d.ID) AS MAX_ID
 FROM Dest d
 GROUP BY d.NAME) n
ON s.NAME = n.NAME
WHERE s.ID > COALESCE(n.MAX_ID,0)
```

However, since there are a lot of entries in the tables, I believe this would not be very performing, unless Hive optimizes it enough automatically, which I am not sure.

What I was hoping to do was something like this:

```
SELECT s.* FROM Source s 
WHERE s.ID > (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(d.ID),0)
              FROM Dest d
              WHERE d.NAME = s.NAME)
```

This way I would avoid calculating **MAX(ID)** for all the entries, and would only calculate it for the current **Name**. But it is apparently not possible in Hive.

So my question is, what would be the best and most performing way to implement this delta detection in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use `left join` and `where`?

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Source s LEFT JOIN
     Dest d
     ON s.NAME = d.NAME AND s.ID = d.ID
WHERE d.NAME IS NULL;
```

If you really need to do this using the maximum id from `Dest`, then your approach with the `GROUP BY` should be fine in Hive.

Comment: The reason is because actually **Source** table is kind of an historical archive, specifically every time some IDs are added to a Name, the previous IDs are also added. E.g. yesterday entries **1, 2** for Name **A** were added, today entries **1,2,3** for Name **A** are added, so **1,2** is added again, then **3**. This makes it difficult to use your approach, or the timestamp. Would my `GROUP BY` approach still perform well with millions of entries, or is there a better way, like some alternative to the second approach?

Comment: @Johnny16 . . . As you described the problem, the `left join` should still work (even with duplicates).  However, it does make the `group by` more palatable.